# Why is my oauth2 config not using my custom UserService?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to use authentication by google. I am using springboot2, so most of the configuration is automatic. The authentication itself works good, but afterwards I would like to populate Principal with my own data (roles, username, and stuff).

I've created MyUserService that exteds DefaultOauth2UserService, and I am trying to use it as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    MyUserService myUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(myUserService);
    }
}
```

I've checked with debuger, that application never actually uses loadUser methods. And here is implementation of MyUserService:

```
@Component
public class MyUserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    public MyUserService(){
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUserService.class).info("initializing user service");
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = super.loadUser(userRequest);
        Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes();

        String emailFromGoogle = (String) attributes.get("email");
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(emailFromGoogle);
        attributes.put("given_name", user.getFirstName());
        attributes.put("family_name", user.getLastName());

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authoritySet = new HashSet<>(oAuth2User.getAuthorities());

        return new DefaultOAuth2User(authoritySet, attributes, "sub");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually the solution was just to add another property for google authentication:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=profile email
```

Not sure, what is the default scope, and why entrance to the service is dependent on scope, but without this line the code never reached my custom service.

Comment: The answer is that by default if you don't provide any scopes when configuring the Google OAuth2 client Spring Boot uses the defaults that are provided in the CommonOAuth2Provider class. And the defaults scopes are: openid, profile, email. By including the openid scope Spring Boot will use OidcUserService implementation of the OAuth2UserService interface not the DefaultOAuth2UserService. So you should extend OidcUserService. And configure it

Comment: Is there by any chance a method to enforce the use of the `OidcUserService` over the `DefaultOAuth2UserService` without adding the  `openid` scope?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing the `@EnableOAuth2Client` annotation at the top of your `SecurityConfig` class.

Regardless, I made an examplewith a Custom user service for oauth2 here https://github.com/TwinProduction/spring-security-oauth2-client-example/ if it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Altough it was not the solution, your project definitely helped me solve it. I'll write it in separate answer, so it's easy to find if someone will step upon the same issue.